# X-Forwarded-Host vs. x-Forwarded-Server

Tags: apache, http-headers

What is the difference between the following headers?

- X-Forwarded-Host
- X-Forwarded-Server

In a setup with Apache being the proxy and Tomcat the origin server I see both of them in the HTTP requests that reach Tomcat. Values were (this is from my own code logging the header name and value pairs with the actual capitalization I encountered)

```
x-forwarded-host some-server
x-forwarded-server some-server.dept.some-uni.edu
```

Are the above values typical? Which of the two should I use to reliably reconstruct the URL asked by the browser? In my case, the browser sent a GET with the `some-server.dept.some-uni.edu` value in the request URL which leads me to think that the `x-forwarded-server` is more relevant to reconstruct the URL. I find this somewhat at odds with the [MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/X-Forwarded-Host) only mentioning `X-Forwarded-Host` and stating that this is the "de-facto standard header for identifying the original host requested by the client" (and containing no documentation on `X-Forwarded-Server`)

[This Apache page](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_proxy.html) OTOH describes both headers as follows:

- **X-Forwarded-Host** The original host requested by the client in the
  Host HTTP request header.
- **X-Forwarded-Server** The hostname of the
  proxy server.

(I appreciate that to reconstruct the URL I also need `X-Forwarded-Proto` and `X-Forwarded-Port`)

Comment: For me, both headers have the same value, which is the full URL hostname. Apache also has the `ProxyPreserveHost` option that you might enable so you don't need to care about the hostname anymore.

Comment: Just observed in a reverse proxy scenario: X-Forwared-Host delivers the hostname as requested by the client (=external name) while X-Forwarded-Server contains the (concrete instance) name/ip from the internal network. I do not really know, if this is the recommended behaviour or not.

Comment: Just a quick comment: using HTTP headers to reconstruct URLs is dangerous. It facilitates Cache Poisoning, which if exploited can allow an attacker to use a cache to execute malicious code.

Comment: @GarrethMcDaid reasonable reverse-proxies should only forward `X-Forwaded-* `-headers from trusted proxies. Otherwise they will be overwritten and therefore should be save.

Answer (score 4):

Since there might be multiple proxies involved in resolving a connection the `X-Forwarded-Host`-Header is the one you should use in the service-application.

The header `X-Forwarded-Server` gets overwritten by each proxy, which is involved in the communication, with the current proxy's hostname.